# VB how to convert string to number and check if it's positive or negative

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a string:   0.2200000, -22.000000, 0.000000

The string is only example, there can be other numbers.

I want to split this string to 3 numbers and check if they are positive or negative, then change to minus or plus.

I want this result as a string:

-0.2200000, 22.000000, 0.000000

I have splited the string:

```
   Dim splited As String() = mystring.Split(New Char() {","c})

  dim deci() as decimal
   For z = 0 To 2

                deci(z) = CDec(Val(splited(z)))
                If deci(z) > 0 Then
                    deci(z) *= -1
                ElseIf deci(z) < 0 Then
                    deci(z) *= -1
                End If

            Next
```

I get error null reference

Comment: You must declare the size before using the array https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this with a one-liner with LINQ (split below for brevity)**

```vb
Dim result = String.Join(", ",
    mystring.Split({","c}).
      Select(Function(s) -Decimal.Parse(s.Trim())))
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this code for you:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Numbers_in_String_Array As String() = {"22.000", "0.00", "-22.00"}
        Dim value As Double
        Dim successful As Boolean
        Dim Numbers_in_String_Array_new(Numbers_in_String_Array.Length - 1) As String

        For i As Integer = 0 To Numbers_in_String_Array.Length - 1 Step 1
            successful = Double.TryParse(Numbers_in_String_Array(i), value)
            If successful Then
                Debug.WriteLine("did work")
            Else
                Debug.WriteLine("did not work")
            End If
            If value < 0.0 Then
                Debug.WriteLine("negative number")
                Numbers_in_String_Array_new(i) = (value * (-1.0)).ToString
            ElseIf value = 0.0 Then
                Debug.WriteLine("0")
                Numbers_in_String_Array_new(i) = (value * (-1.0)).ToString
            ElseIf value > 0.0 Then
                Debug.WriteLine("positive number")
                Numbers_in_String_Array_new(i) = (value * (-1.0)).ToString
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

The only problem that remains is the set culture in Visual Studio. The program notices where the computer is currently. This means, if your string is `"22.000"` for example, it becomes 22,000 (twenty-two thousand). If you don't want that, then you have to replace `"."c` with `","c`.
You can also convert to string with the given culture.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private ReadOnly Polish As New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("pl-PL")
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Numbers_in_String_Array As String() = {"22.000", "0.00", "-22.00"}
        Dim Numbers_in_String_Array_new(Numbers_in_String_Array.Length - 1) As String
        For i As Integer = 0 To Numbers_in_String_Array.Length - 1 Step 1
            Numbers_in_String_Array_new(i) = Numbers_in_String_Array(i).Replace("."c, ","c)
        Next
        Dim value As Double
        Dim successful As Boolean
        Dim Numbers_in_String_Array_new_new(Numbers_in_String_Array.Length - 1) As String

        For i As Integer = 0 To Numbers_in_String_Array_new.Length - 1 Step 1
            successful = Double.TryParse(Numbers_in_String_Array_new(i), value)
            If successful Then
                Debug.WriteLine("did work")
            Else
                Debug.WriteLine("did not work")
            End If
            If value < 0.0 Then
                Debug.WriteLine("negative number")
                Numbers_in_String_Array_new_new(i) = (value * (-1.0)).ToString(Polish)
            ElseIf value = 0.0 Then
                Debug.WriteLine("0")
                Numbers_in_String_Array_new_new(i) = (value * (-1.0)).ToString(Polish)
            ElseIf value > 0.0 Then
                Debug.WriteLine("positive number")
                Numbers_in_String_Array_new_new(i) = (value * (-1.0)).ToString(Polish)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```